# Get value from json array object postgres

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, select

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT tags
FROM (
    SELECT trm.dado_id
        , json_agg(json_build_object('field',trm.nome, 'value',trm.valor)) AS tags
    FROM tb_dados trm
    JOIN tb_table1 t on trm.dado_id = t.id
    WHERE t.id = trm.dado_id
    GROUP BY trm.dado_id
    ) tabletags;
```

It returns me a lot of rows with json array field like this:

```
1  |   [{"field" : "EMISSION", "value" : "21/04/2020 00:38:00"}, {"field" : "DATA CREATION", "value" : "21/09/1989"}, {"field" : "SERIE NUMBER", "value" : "00.000.000-11"}]
2  |   [{"field" : "DATA CREATION", "value" : "21/09/1998"}, {"field" : "SERIE NUMBER", "value" : "00.000.000-7"}]
3  |   [{"field" : "EMISSION", "value" : "21/04/2020 00:38:00"}, {"field" : "DATA CREATION", "value" : "21/09/1989"}, {"field" : "SERIE NUMBER", "value" : "00.000.000-7"}]
4  |   [{"field" : "EMISSION", "value" : "21/04/2020 00:38:00"}, {"field" : "DATA CREATION", "value" : "21/09/1989"}, {"field" : "SERIE NUMBER", "value" : "00.000.000-11"}]
```

...

Well, I want to query the row with has the SERIE NUMBER equals 00.000.000-11.
There's a way of filter it?

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the aggregation query with a `HAVING` clause. Also note that the subquery is not necessary here, and that the `WHERE` clause is redondant with the `ON` clause of the `JOIN`.

So:

```
SELECT json_agg(json_build_object('field', trm.nome, 'value', trm.valor)) AS tags
FROM tb_dados trm
JOIN tb_table1 t on trm.dado_id = t.id
GROUP BY trm.dado_id
HAVING bool_or(trm.nome = 'SERIE NUMBER' AND trm.valor = '00.000.000-11')
```

Side note: is there any reason why you are using `json` instead of `jsonb`? The latter offers more functionalities, and should be generaly preferred. You can use `jsonb_build_objet()` and `jsonb_agg()` instead of the corresponding `json_*` functions.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But filter by having clause, how can I ensure that this "valor" matches exacly to this "nome"?